# Material UI "&.Mui-selected" and "& .Mui-selected"

Tags: material-ui

What is the difference between "&.Mui-selected" and "& .Mui-selected" in material ui ? In case of "& .Mui-selected", There is a space between '&' and '.'.What is the significance of this space between '&' and '.' ?

Comment: The space means it will match a [selected descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) of elements with the class referred to by `&`. Without the space, it means it matches selected elements with the class referred to by `&` (i.e. the matched elements would have both the `Mui-selected` class and the class that `&` indicates).

Answer (score 0):

As a previous comment mentions, the significance isn't due to MUI, but to have CSS selectors work. To answer your question, here's the difference between the string with and without the space.

## With no space.

`"&.Mui-selected"` resolves to this CSS selector: `.SomeMuiGeneratedClassName.Mui-selected`. This targets elements whose `class` attribute contains two strings: `SomeMuiGeneratedClassName` and `Mui-selected`:

```css
.SomeMuiGeneratedClassName.Mui-selected {
  background: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- MATCHED -->
  <div class="SomeMuiGeneratedClassName Mui-selected">I am your match!
  </div>
  <!-- NOT MATCHED -->
  <div class="SomeMuiGeneratedClassName">
    <div class="Mui-selected">I am NOT your match!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## With a space.

`"& .Mui-selected"` resolves to this CSS selector: `.SomeMuiGeneratedClassName .Mui-selected`. This is a **descendant selector**. It will gather any elements whose `class` attribute contains `SomeMuiGeneratedClassName`. From that collection it will select any *children* (descendants) who have `Mui-selected` in their `class` attribute string.

```css
.SomeMuiGeneratedClassName .Mui-selected {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- NOT MATCHED -->
  <div class="SomeMuiGeneratedClassName Mui-selected">I am NOT your match!</div>
  <!-- MATCHED -->
  <div class="SomeMuiGeneratedClassName">
    <div class="Mui-selected">I am your match!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```